# A question about the size of Android ICONS

Tags: android

**Why is my Android icon very vague? Is it the size problem?**

[image: Err]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My icons file size is 24 x 24 px

Comment: Please read: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

Comment: I think you mean "blurry" not "vague".

Comment: And in fact, you can see why it is blurry from looking at the pixels.  It looks like this icon once had a different size, and has been converted to 24 x 24 by something that has use [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art#Techniques) in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! 24x24 is pretty low, IMO. You're going to run into size issues with static PNGs quite a bit. I'd recommend using vectors for this instead, per this article: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

It's possible to build an app with only one set of PNGs (the launcher icon shown on the homescreen) and use vectors literally everywhere else - and that sole PNG is because of some unexpected compatibility issues I found. Theoretically, you could use vectors only!

It appears the icon in your screenshot is pretty generic. You could probably just generate a Vector Asset for it by right-clicking the drawable folder and picking that option.